# Foreward declaring a class defined in an unnamed namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I was trying to extend a pre-existing class, and wanted to add a new functionality to it.
I created a new class to perform the new extended functionality, but since this functionality was too specific to pre-existing class, I move the class implementation to an unnamed namespace in .cpp file of pre-existing class.( It is in unnamed namespace because it does not really belong to the namespace in which pre-existing class remains.  ).
The per-existing class is still supposed to store a pointer for this new class.
I made implementation like this:

I have the pre-existing class in a namespace say ( xyz ):
My .h looks like this:

```
// Forward declare the class
namespace
{
// This is the class in which I have kept my extended functionality
class MyClass;
}

namespace xyz
{
  class Subject
  {
  public:
    Subject();
  private:
//keeping the pointer in Pr-Existing class
    std::unique_ptr< MyClass > mMyClass
  };
}
```

in .cpp I have the definition of MyClass in an unnamed namespace.

So my .cpp looks like this:

```
namespace
{
  class MyClass
  {
    .
    .
    .
  };
}

xyz::Subject::Subject()
{
  mMyClass.reset( new MyClass() );
}
```

Now I am unable to compile the program, Compiler believes that the MyClass which is declared in both the places is different.
I get an error like this:

error: reference to 'MyClass' is ambiguous
        mMyClass.reset( new MyClass) );
                                    ^
.h: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'MyClass'
class MyClass;
      ^
.cpp: note: candidate found by name lookup is '::MyClass'
        class MyClass : public MyClass

I can resolve it by keeping MyClass in namespace xyz.
But is there a way to do it without that..?

Comment: Why can you not name the namespace, e.g. `namespace fwd`? Or leave `MyClass` outside of a snamespace?

Comment: It is preferable to put definitions into named namespace to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Every unnamed namespace is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.

Seems like what I was trying to achieve it is not a good design practice.
My declaring the class in unnamed namespace in .h is a bad idea.
It will be available to all those files where I will include this header.
In nutshell it is reverse of what I want ( keep this class private )
Now I am going to use pImpl idiom instead of this.